# XFCE change brightness steps and/or change brightness key behavior

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, brightness, xfce

I'm trying to change the brightness steps in XFCE from 10 to 20. I'd like the ability to gradually change the laptop's brightness by 5% instead of 10%. Is there a way to set this up with a config file for XFCE?

If that is not an option, I have thought of another way: I know that I can disable XFCE's power settings from handling brightness keys, but setting up a shortcut in keyboard preferences does not seem to be able to override this.

Is there another way I can remap what `XF86MonBrightnessUp` and `XF86MonBrightnessDown` do when pressed?  Specifically, I'd like `Up` to use the command `lumeus +5%` and `Down` to use the command `lumeus -5%`.

Can either idea be done while using XFCE with its XFWM?

Answer (score 6):

## No need to recompile the `xfce4-power-manager`

There really is no need to recompile `xfce4-power-manager`.

Firstly, install `xbacklight`

```
$ sudo apt install xbacklight
```

Secondly, check whether you have control over the backlight.

```
$ xbacklight -1
$ xbacklight +5
```

Should these commands result in a **`No outputs have backlight property`** error,
then [follow these remediating steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1060843/164341) before proceeding.

Once `xbacklight -1` and `xbacklight +1` work from the command line, proceed with assigning these commands to respectively the `XF86MonBrightnessDown` and `XF86MonBrightnessUp` keys. This is done by hitting those keys when asked by the Settings → Keyboard → Application Shortcuts application.

Finally, **reboot** for these changes to take effect.

[image: Keyboard settings]

Answer (score 3):

Another year passes and another year of no progress on this issue despite easy solutions posted online (e.g., [How to obtain more brightness levels using Fn+keys in Xfce?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140278/23408)).

You need to recompile Xfce Power Manager with minor changes in the code.

1. Download Power Manager from here:
   http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.12/src/xfce4-power-manager-1.4.3.tar.bz2
2. Unpack it and `cd` into the folder.
3. Open `common/xfpm-brightness.c` in a text editor: 
   (e.g., `gvim common/xfpm-brightness.c`).
4. Change line 515:

   ```
   set_level = MAX (hw_level/1.5, brightness->priv->min_level);
   ```
5. Change line 475:

   ```
   set_level = MIN (hw_level*2 + (hw_level==0), brightness->priv->max_level );
   ```
6. Save and close.
7. Type `./configure` at the command prompt. You're kind of on your own here... there will be errors and you need to fix them. E.g., on Xubuntu 18.04 I needed to install several things:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-dev
   sudo apt-get install libxfce4ui-1-dev
   sudo apt-get install libnotify-dev
   sudo apt-get install libupower-glib-dev
   ```
8. Once configure is complete, type `make`.
9. Once make completes, type `sudo make install`.
10. Logout and login. Voilà! You have smaller backlight increments.

Comment: Or in one go for Xubuntu LTS 18.04: `sudo apt install libdbus-glib-1-dev libxfce4ui-1-dev libnotify-dev libupower-glib-dev intltool`

Answer (score 1):

Before downloading (step 1 above), check the version number:

```
xfce4-power-manager --version
```

Then download the correct version from here:

https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager

Last issue, I seem to run into a polkit error when running the custom xfce4 power manager (related to [this][1] but no fix).

[1]: Authentication needed to run xfpm-power-backlight-helper as super user
 https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11190

Comment: If you are Jaja Banksy, please go to [the Contact page](/contact) and select ‘‘I need to merge user profiles’’.  Then just [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1328075/edit) [your answer](https://superuser.com/q/1279727/354511#1328075).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on arch and recompiled xfce4 power manager as proposed. I also had the polkit problem after installing the compiled power manager. Here is how I solved it so that everything works with customizable brightness steps, the exponential option and the Fn key combination:

1. `git clone https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfce4-power-manager`
2. `cd xfce4-power-manager`
3. `git checkout master`; I'm on commit ID `eee63912efb5b3d01000c63bd306b4a629ec6f7f` which is basically some commits ahead of v1.6.1.
4. `wget https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=7728 -O brightness.patch`
5. `git apply brightness.patch`
6. `./autogen.sh`
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`
9. reboot
10. now authentication is asked when using Fn+Brightness control keys; that is because the path of xfpm-power-backlight-helper has changed
11. `sudo vim /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.xfce.power.policy`
12. change the XML node

`<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper</annotate>`

to

`<annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/local/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper</annotate>`

Answer (score 0):

[ub_marco’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1279727/150988#1346106) almost solves it for me. 
After `sudo make install` finishes the installation,
I need to edit the file `org.xfce.power.policy` through this command:

```
sudo vim /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.xfce.power.policy
```

and change the following lines in the file:

```
 <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/local/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper</annotate>

 <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/local/sbin/xfce4-pm-helper</annotate>
```

so that they point to `/usr/sbin` rather than `/usr/local/sbin`.

Each time I recompile, I need to re-edit this file. 
Some path must be wrong in the Makefile, but I can't track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you install some other packages together, the brightness and sound keys should work without any configuration:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-goodies xorg dbus-x11 x11-xserver-utils
```